# Text summarization with limited number of words

Tags: nlp, automatic-summarization

I am reviewing summarization techniques and haven't (yet) found an approach to limit the length of a summary. So for example a summarization function that gives me a summary that is `< 500 words`.

Can you point me in the right direction? Are there approaches/implementations out there that try to solve this challenge?

Appreciate your replies!

Comment: Please make a clear definition of your problem, i.e. what you mean when you say summary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sure can,

for example in [**latent semantic analysis**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_semantic_analysis) you can fixate number of topics (which is actually size of the decomposition matrix) beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

LDA, [Latent Dirchlet Allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_Dirichlet_allocation), also allows to specify number of topics.